# i want to replace a word in a paragraph using reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey My name is +++Vijay+++.

in here, this word called Vijay can be differ when are retrieving from db.
i have to replace this word using java script

Comment: Could you provide more information on what the paragraph looks like, and how you want to replace the string? Is it a template where you want to just change the name so it's addressed to different people?

Comment: Try regex for these type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#:%7E:text=The%20replace()%20method%20returns,first%20occurrence%20will%20be%20replaced.) which allows you to use regex to replace anything in the string. for example:

If you want to replace "Vijay" with "Mark" you can:

```js
const string = 'Hey My name is +++Vijay+++.';

console.log(string.replace(/\++(.*)\++/, 'Mark'));
```

- `\++` will match one or more of the special character `+`.
- `.*` will match anything between the pluses `+++` and then the `()` surrounding it will capture the value.